# Overlay a bootstrap 4 transparent navbar over an image using flexbox

Tags: flexbox, bootstrap-4, navbar, overlay

I need to place a transparent bootstrap 4 navbar over a full screen image utilising flexbox. I need to be able to expand a carousel container (swiper.js) to fill the view port.

I have managed to expand the carousel container to fill the view port but the navbar does not appear transparently over it. To view what it currently does [click here][1]. To view what I would like to achieve [click here][2]

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-transparent">
            <div class="navbar-brand pr-5">
                <a class="d-inline-block" routerLink="/home">
                    <img src="assets/logo-dark.png" alt="" height="43">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbars" id="navbar-navigation">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link text-uppercase" href="#>Home</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link text-uppercase" href="#>Service</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link text-uppercase" href="#>Product</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-fill">
        <div class="swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide bg-cover" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1920x1080');">
                    Slide 1</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide bg-cover" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1920x1080');">
                    Slide 2</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide bg-cover" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1920x1080');">
                    Slide 3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<main class="page-content content-boxed">
    Page content goes here ...
</main>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eB42.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fr9H.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your image overlap to the navbar, you just have to give ***position:absolute*** property to the navbar.

```
.navbar{
   position:absolute;
}
```